# Android permissions UI issue with multiple dialogs

Tags: java, android, user-interface, permissions

I'm trying to refactor a piece of code that deals with Android permissions. It works fine, except for one annoying UI bug that has caused me a lot of headaches. Here's the code:

```
private void getPermissions() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {

        List<String> permissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<String>();

        final List<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (!addPermission(permissionsList, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION))
            permissionsNeeded.add(accessLocation);
        if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.CAMERA))
            permissionsNeeded.add(accessCamera);

        if (permissionsList.size() > 0) {
            if (permissionsNeeded.size() > 0) {
                requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                        REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void showMessageOK (int message, final String perm) {

    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(perm)) {

        new AlertDialog.Builder(CreateSessionActivity.this)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setTitle("Permission required")
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        dialog.dismiss();
                        requestPermissions(new String[] {perm},
                                REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);

                    }
                })
                .create()
                .show();
    }
}

private boolean addPermission(List<String> permissionsList, String permission) {

    if (checkSelfPermission(permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        permissionsList.add(permission);

        //check for rationale
        if (!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<>();

    perms.put(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    perms.put(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    // Fill with results
    for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
        perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);

    if (perms.get(accessLocation) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        showMessageOK(R.string.permdesc_access_location,
                accessLocation);
    }

    if (perms.get(accessCamera) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        showMessageOK(R.string.permdesc_access_camera,
                accessCamera);
    }
}
```

It basically gets a list of permissions that are not already granted by the user, cycles through them and prompts the user to grant each. Once it's finished, it checks for any remaining permissions that have not been granted and prompts the user again with information on why that permission is required and the result of not allowing it, until he either accepts or chooses "do not ask again".

My problem occurs with the chained "if" statements in onRequestPermissionResult(). As you may guess, if multiple permission conditions are true, then each dialog opens *underneath* the current existing dialog. This results in a "jumping" dialog effect between one dialog closing and the next displaying. I've tried case and if/elseif statements to combat this, but it causes problems with the rest of my permission logic.

Does anyone have a clean solution for this? I would be grateful.

Comment: IMHO, the cleanest solution is to get rid of all the `showMessageOK()` calls. The user knows that the user granted you the permission, because *the user just did it*. Do not thank them for granting the permission -- do whatever it was that the user asked for that needed the permission.

Comment: Make sure all the permissions you asking for also declaring in your `AndroidManifest` file

Answer (score 0):

Well, this may not be the cleanest code but,

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {

    List<String> permissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<String>();            
    for(int i=0; i<4;i++){
            checkAndAsk(i);
    }
    if (permissionsList.size() > 0) {
        if (permissionsNeeded.size() > 0) {
            requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                    REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
        }
    }
}
//out of the get permissions method
public void checkAndAsk(int i){
            switch(i){
                case 0:
                    if (!addPermission(permissionsList, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION))
                        permissionsNeeded.add(accessLocation);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    if (!addPermission(permissionsList, android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS))
                        permissionsNeeded.add(readContacts);
                    break;
                //You get the idea
            }
  }
```

Basically you iterate through the permissions by passing a parameter of which permission you will ask for. Once a permission is granted/declined, it breaks, moving onto the second permission until all are done.

In theory this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code :

```
private void RequestAllPermissions() {

        String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.INTERNET, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS};

        if (!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, REQUESTCODE_PERMISSION_ALL);
        } else

    }

public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;

    }


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUESTCODE_PERMISSION_ALL: {

            boolean allpermissiongranted = true;
            if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {
                    if (grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        allpermissiongranted = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else
                allpermissiongranted = false;

            if (allpermissiongranted) {
                //do task

            } else {

                new SweetAlertDialog(mContext, SweetAlertDialog.WARNING_TYPE)
                        .setTitleText("Permission Not Granted")
                        .setContentText("Kindly grant all requested permission to proceed.")
                        .setConfirmText("Request")
                        .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sDialog) {
                                sDialog.dismissWithAnimation();
                                RequestAllPermissions();
                            }
                        })
                        .setCancelText("Exit")
                        .setCancelClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog) {
                                sweetAlertDialog.dismissWithAnimation();
                                finish();
                            }
                        })
                        .show();
            }

        }
    }

}
```